# Custom MXNet Operators and kAddTo

Tags: mxnet

I'm a writing a C++ custom operator in MXNet and am having trouble finding documentation on when `kAddTo` is set in an operator invocation. As a minimal example, let's say that my new operator is called `foo()` and I want to perform the following calculation:

```py
A = mx.sym.Variable('A')
B = mx.sym.Variable('B')
T = mx.sym.foo(A)
T += mx.sym.foo(B)
```

In general, how do I ensure that the fourth line above accumulates into T as opposed to creating a new temporary storage for the result of `mx.sym.foo(B)` and then performing the `T = T + temp` calculation?

*(Using the Kernighan-Ritchie debugger, aka print statements, I found that `kWriteTo` is set on both lines three and four. The enum `kAddTo` is never set.)*

A bit more detail concerning my specific problem: in my current implementation `foo()` *zeroes out* the output memory before performing a calculation which populates it with the appropriate values. I definitely only want to perform this zeroing out when creating a new output location, not when accumulating into an existing one.

**Update**

Offline, a colleague suggested using

```py
mx.sym.elemwise_add(lhs=T, rhs=mx.sym.foo(B), out=T)
```

in place of line 4, above. However, I still saw that `kWriteTo` was being set in both lines of computation. I then received the following response:

> **“Memory planning and inplace operations are automatic. It will be done automatically. Users don’t need to worry about it.”**, which probably means that `req[0]` is not an accurate indicator in this case. If you want to verify whether it’s an inplace addTo, you can print out the value of `outputs[0].dptr_` and `lhs.dptr_` to see whether they are equal.

I haven't checked this, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator can not control in which mode it will be executed. The thing is, only graph optimizer knows the context in which the operator is used and can make a decision if the operator need to be executed in the `kWriteTo` or `kAddTo`. More precisely, this happens [here in the method DetectInplaceAddTo](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/986b736b816018b96e9d1e2c358bb7665b80944d/src/executor/inplace_addto_detect_pass.cc#L16) .And even if in some cases it has been executed in `kAddTo` this behavior might be changed in the future due to change in the logic that optimizes the computational graph.

> “Memory planning and inplace operations are automatic. It will be done
>   automatically. Users don’t need to worry about it.”

This means that operator can not control in which mode it is execute, however the operatro MUST strictly obey the mode that has been requested (`kWriteTo` or `kAddTo`). For example if the mode is `kWriteTo` and the operator tries to add diff to the outputs, instead of overriding what is in it, this would lead to an unpredictable results since outputs might be populated with the garbage. On the other hand if the mode is `kAddTo` however the operator does not support it it might be even worse, since, instead of adding the results to the outputs it will just override the outputs(cases like this usually very hard to debug). This leads, time to time, to bugs like [this one](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/6526).

So, in short:

> In general, how do I ensure that the fourth line above accumulates
>   into T as opposed to creating a new temporary storage for the result
>   of mx.sym.foo(B) and then performing the T = T + temp calculation?

You can not, it's not the operator decision in which mode to be executed. Even if the configuration is using mode `kAddTo` with future versions of the MXNet. Also in the future there might be possible to create new APIs to send a hint to a graph optimizer (or suggestion) to use particular mode. But I'm not aware of such development.

Now the question: "in which particular case MXNet 0.10/0.11 will use `kAddTo`"?

This is tricky, by looking on the [following code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/986b736b816018b96e9d1e2c358bb7665b80944d/src/executor/inplace_addto_detect_pass.cc#L39):

```
  for (uint32_t nid = 0; nid < idx.num_nodes(); ++nid) {
    const auto& inode = idx[nid];
    if (inode.source->op() != ewise_plus_op) continue; // <= HERE
    int sid = storage_id[idx.entry_id(inode.inputs[0])];
```

It looks like the `kAddTo` used only during `_grad_add`, which is sad. Also this might be a bug, since maybe instead of:

```
static const Op* ewise_plus_op = Op::Get("_grad_add");
```

Actual intention was:

```
static const Op* ewise_plus_op = Op::Get("elemwise_add");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive response! Concerning the comment

```This means that operator can not control in which mode it is execute, however the operatro MUST strictly obey the mode that has been requested (kWriteTo or kAddTo).```

my custom operator checks which mode the operator was called in and zeroes out the output data pointer only if the mode is `kWriteTo`. I assume that when the mode is `kAddTo` the operation is treated as in-place and, as I defined, the first input is mapped to the first output. Is this correct design or is this also somehow automatically handled?